# What is the point of making a test for Pageable?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, junit

I should write a test with Mockito for this method:

```
public Optional<Page<User>> getAllByPage(Integer pageSize, Integer page) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize);
    return userRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

I cannot understand for the longest time, what should be the test? What is the point of testing a Pageable, this method returns all users, so I should maybe just check if the method returns all users? Am I making a mistake somewhere in the logic?

Answer (score 0):

You should only unit test code that you implement. Since in that method that is almost none, I wouldn't unit test it. But I would make sure that Integration and System testing covered that method in all possible iterations to increase my trust on it.

Also, imagine that you provide a wrong page size or page number? what would happen? Can you know without testing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is going to be pretty much opinion-based.

The problem is you're looking at the implementation. If you have an IDE, use code folding to see just the method signature. Then, look at what the requirements for this method are.

Now, you can test it. Just write code to check if the method conforms to requirements (if specific input parameters produce desired output, what happens for illegal parameters). And you're done. Later on someone can change how the method is implemented. If the tests work anyway, you are sure no-one broke anything by changing the implementation.

So, ideally you would supply a mocked repository with part of desired behavior implemented, so it returns the data you want when queried with `Pageable`.

This way you can just assert on returned data, and your tests are solid - i.e. if someone changes to another implementation, but it still produces desired output, your tests pass.

Compare that to calling `verify`. This test is brittle, since on changed implementation it will fail. Why should it? Which business requirement was broken so that the test failed? Well, none.

And if you have a test-suite to prove your mocked data layer behaves the same way as the real one (to the desired level), you can have insanely fast pseudo-integration tests, which can be easily run before the real ones. And you're testing the real stuff, the functionality, in implementation-agnostic way.